# Adding social login to native apps using spring security oauth

Tags: android, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-oauth2

I've been following this link https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2 for implementing security to my own resource server. My final goal was to have custom login oauth server to access resource server from an android app which I've achieved using grant_type=password.

Now I would like to add social logins like Facebook to the same flow. I was able to make it work for web apps easily,I even got the accessToken from facebook in native android app but now what? After so much searching I was not able to find anything good for an android app. So my questions are:

1. How to add social login using spring oauth2 to an android app. Any links?
2. Should I be using Spring social with spring security for my goal. If yes, how?
3. I've been using JDBCTokenStore to persist my tokens in case my server restarts. If I get my token to server somehow how should I store it?

Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too deep into the details, you can take the token you get from the client and use it to create a new connection via the connection repository. Of course, you'll also need to know which use the connection belongs to. In the end, the code will look *something* like this:

Code:

```java
UsersConnectionRepository ucr = ...; // probably injected
ConnectionRepository cr = ucr.createConnectionRepository(userId); // you determine the userId somehow
ConnectionData cd = new ConnectionData(...); // lots of params...you'll fill those in.
FacebookConnectionFactory fcf = ...; // create or inject this
Connection<Facebook> conn = fcf.createConnection(cd);
cr.addConnection(conn);
```

As you can see, the code above is rough...I'm leaving a lot for you to fill in. But that's roughly how you'd do it.